# File Listener in Informatica Cloud

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-cloud, informatica-powerexchange, informatica-data-integration-hub

Is there any "option" to notify the end-use if a particular file is not arriving during the scheduled time in the file listener of IICS or coming in after the scheduled time?

If so, what is it?

Else, how can we achieve this?

Comment: can you create a command task which will run as pre-process and chekc the file - if it exists, it will not do anything. If doesnt, it will send a mail and generate 0 byte file or no file (to fail the workflow).

Comment: Will try this. Thanks a lot Koushik.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should be feasible. Use `Parallel Paths`. On one path run your `File Watch Task`. On the other put a `Wait` task followed by a `Decision` that again splits the paths to two. `Decision` should check e.g. your main task start time. If it's set - it means your job has been started already. If not use `throw` to report an error.

Here's how I'd imagine that (general idea, some tuning might be required):

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation buddy. This was really helpful for our scenario.

Comment: If it was, consider marking this answer as correct and upvoting, so it may help other at some point.

Comment: Buddy, I did upvote but due to less no. of reputations it's not displaying publicly over here. However, the feedback has been recorded. Apologies!